# Firefox Updates Don't (Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: firefox, updates

I religiously update my system. Since Firefox 10, the updates show up in the PPA, I install them, but nothing changes. (and Firefox keeps nagging me: "update available")

I just tried again for FF 14.

Now, synaptics says I have 14.0.1 installed, but Firefox version (Help -> About) still reads 10.0.2

Any thoughts (short of uninstalling and re-installing?)

Comment: From which PPA you are installing , remove the PPA and it will no longer nag you.

Comment: Have you tied updating from terminal?

Comment: @tijybba It's Firefox itself that keep nagging me (update available! Visit mozilla to download) or some such... Synaptics seems normal.

Comment: Try reisntalling Firefox from synaptic. And then check its Version `( i know it shows 14, but still do try)` , Check for Firefox PPA in `Software sources` and disable it. Because normally in Ubuntu , firefox never shows that Message. About PPA i don't know.

Comment: Hmm. I did have the firefox (stable) ppa enabled... (not sure why) disabling it and trying a reinstall.

Comment: Awesome :/ just removed Firefox 14 via synaptic... and yet... here I am using it (or rather FF10). Wonder if I installed FF10 non-traditionally somehow.

Comment: Ok... so how do I uninstall a program that appears to be living outside the aptitude system? Just did a --purge remove firefox and it says its already gone. Yet I'm using it now... Crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1528878

See #3

When Firefox is downloaded directly and installed via the install script, it sets `/usr/bin/firefox.ubuntu` as the launch path.

`sudo mv /usr/bin/firefox.ubuntu /usr/bin/firefox`

Did the trick.